# React Testing Library + Material UI (v4) Hidden component

Tags: reactjs, testing, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm new to react testing library. I wanted to test my code wrapped with `Hidden` Component of material UI but the test fails (even though my component is visible in the DOM).

**Component**

```
import { Hidden } from '@material-ui/core'
import React from 'react'

function App() {

    return (
        <>
            <h4>This is always visible</h4>
            <Hidden xsUp={true}>
                <h3>The hidden element</h3>
            </Hidden>
        </>
    )

}
```

xsUp set to **true** **hides** **the h3** in DOM and **false** **shows** **the h3** in DOM

**But I don't understand why setting it to false fails the below test** even though the component is visible in DOM

**Test**

```
test("Hidden element should be visible", async () => {
  render(<App />);

  const h3 = await screen.findByRole('heading', { name: "The hidden element"}) // same effect if I use screen.getByRole or getByText

  expect(h3).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Note: I tested if h3 is not wrapped in the Hidden element the test passes. But setting xsUp to true or false fails the test.

[image]

Please try out here https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-boyd-uzv9w?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that I can wrap my component with `MuiThemeProvider` as shown which passes the test if `xsUp = false` and fails if `xsUp = true` as expected

**Test**

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Greet from './Greet'
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
const theme = createTheme({ props: { MuiWithWidth: { initialWidth: 'xs' } } }) 


test("Hidden element should be visible", async () => {

  /*  render(<App />); */

  render(
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Greet />
    </MuiThemeProvider>

  );
  const h3 = await screen.findByRole('heading', { name: "The hidden element", hidden: true })
  expect(h3).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**Reference**: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2179 (nicolasremise commented on Sep 9, 2019)